# Film set on an escape pod from a sabotaged space station

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie when I was about 12 (20 years ago), and it's stuck with me for some reason.

A group of survivors are onboard an escape pod after their space station exploded. Amongst them is a dwarf engineer with a cyber arm and a blind man. The members start dying and it turns out the blind man (who is not really) is the killer, and the original saboteur.

I would guess it can out after Alien, it has a similar aesthetic (although much lower budget). It may have been a straight-to-video release.

Comment: earlier duplicate at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13030/a-spaceship-crew-stuck-in-a-damaged-spaceship-thats-losing-power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [LifePod](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107415/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt), it was out in 1993 so its within that timeline.

> Lifepod chronicles the trip of eight passengers after the ship they were traveling on blew up on Christmas Eve. Immediately people start dying. The passengers begin to investigate why the ...

Comment: That's it :) So it had a fine pedigree: 'A futuristic retelling of the classic Hitchcock film "Lifeboat"' written by John Steinbeck. Maybe I'll check out the original. That's made my day, thx a lot.

Comment: No Problem. Have a good week. :)

Comment: +1 for this, I remember it quite well. Ron Silver was the blind man. Great twist.